# Download IBM HTTPServer 9.0 for AIX

Tags: aix, ibmhttpserver

From where can I download `IBM HTTPServer-9.0` for AIX. My AIX machine is a virtual machine and it doesn't have internet connectivity.

Comment: The IBM Installation Manager Packaging Utility (pucl) will let you build a zip from the online repository, if you don't have access to original media.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a trial version here.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21972167